# How can I remove slash from renderRow of type date?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I want to remove the slash (/) between day/month/year in date format, in Symfony 1.4, when use

```
<?php echo $form['birthday']->renderRow(array('class' => 'date')) ?>
```

Which result in:

```
<tr>
  <th><label for="profile_birthday">Birthday</label></th>
  <td>
     <select class="date" name="profile[birthday][month]" id="profile_birthday_month">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="1">01</option>
        ...
        <option value="12">12</option>
     </select>
     /
     <select class="date" name="profile[birthday][day]" id="profile_birthday_day">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="1">01</option>
        ...
        <option value="31">31</option>
     </select>
     /
     <select class="date" name="profile[birthday][year]" id="profile_birthday_year">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="2006">2006</option>
        ...
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
     </select>
 </td>
</tr>
```

But I want:

```
<tr>
  <th><label for="profile_birthday">Birthday</label></th>
  <td>
     <select class="date" name="profile[birthday][month]" id="profile_birthday_month">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="1">01</option>
        ...
        <option value="12">12</option>
     </select>
     <select class="date" name="profile[birthday][day]" id="profile_birthday_day">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="1">01</option>
        ...
        <option value="31">31</option>
     </select>
     <select class="date" name="profile[birthday][year]" id="profile_birthday_year">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="2006">2006</option>
        ...
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
     </select>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the date format for the widget in your form class. Add the following code to the `configure()` method in `lib/form/doctrine/MyForm.class.php`:

```
$this->setWidget('foo', new sfWidgetFormDate(
    array('format' => '%month% ... %day% ... %year%')
));
```

Replacing the widget name `foo` with the appropriate name in your case. Hope this helps :)

**Edit:**

[You can find more information on sfWidgetFormDate and other widgets here](http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/A-Widgets#chapter_a_sub_sfwidgetformdate)